# SoundCloud player widget disabling sound stats

Tags: api, soundcloud

I was looking at the SoundCloud player widget API and trying to resolve an issue I am having with a smaller scale player. Currently the track artist, name and all of the SoundCloud track stats load. I get an ugly overlap due to the size of the player. Is there a way to disable those sound cloud stats using the API?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmfl8.png

Answer (score 1):

The name is a bit confusing, but if you add `&show_playcount=false` to the embed code, they'll be hidden. Example:

https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F2860118&show_playcount=false